# Computing Invariant Subspaces of Matrix Groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, computer-algebra-systems, gap

Does anyone have a program written in Mathematica (or SAGE or GAP) that computes the invariant subspace lattice of a matrix group?

Comment: It depends a little on the matrix group. If the matrix group is the one element group over the 6x6 matrices over Z/11Z then the lattice has 3 billion subspaces. If the associated module is "square-free" then things are much nicer, and GAP can handle this without trouble (look for the meataxe). What sort of matrix group do you have? Approximate numbers for the dimension, field, number of indecomposable summands, Loewy length of the summands would be helpful to suggest a method.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like an awfully difficult problem unless the matrix group has a nice structure.

Comment: The GAP command for this is MTX.BasesSubmodules which, as Jack Schmidt said, is in the Meataxe chapter. MTX.BasesMinimalSubmodules and MTX.BasesMaximalSubmodules are also useful if there are too many of them.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the unanswered queue (or, if you are happy with this, I can re-post your comment as a CW answer).

Answer (score 2):

*I am posting a CW answer to remove this question from the unanswered queue. Thanks to @Derek Holt and @Jack Schmidt for the comments that I've converted to the answer*

It depends a little on the matrix group. If the matrix group is the one element group over the 6x6 matrices over Z/11Z then the lattice has 3 billion subspaces. If the associated module is "square-free" then things are much nicer, and GAP can handle this without trouble. The GAP command for this is `MTX.BasesSubmodules` which is described in the [Meataxe chapter](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap69.html#X7BF9D3CB81A8F8F9). `MTX.BasesMinimalSubmodules` and `MTX.BasesMaximalSubmodules` are also useful if there are too many of them.